# Django-filter and restframework pagination infinitely appends query

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a viewset with settings looking like below

```
class JobPostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = filters.JobPostFilter

    pagination_class = DefaultCursorPagination
```

My filter is as below

```
class JobPostFilter(FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = models.JobPost
        fields = {
            'company__type': [
                'in'
            ],
            'approval_status': [
                'exact'
            ],
            'sex': [
                'in'
            ],
            'education': [
                'in'
            ],
            'business_strategy': [
                'in',
            ],
            'base_salary': [
                'in'
            ],
            'settlement_support': [
                'in'
            ],
            'scout_royalty': [
                'in'
            ],
            'mortgage': [
                'in'
            ],
            'db_availability': [
                'in'
            ],
            'experience': [
                'in'
            ]
        }
```

Default cursor pagination is as below

```
class DefaultCursorPagination(CursorPagination):
    ordering = '-id'
```

When I send a pagination request to `http://localhost/api/paginate?approval_status=true` I get additional `?approval_status=true` appended to the URL every time I paginate.

For example `nextLink` value from first pagination from django returns `http://localhost/api/paginate?approval_status=true&approval_status=true&cursor=xxx`. The next pagination returns `http://localhost/api/paginate?approval_status=true&approval_status=true&approval_status=true&cursor=xxx` and so on, infinitely adding existing query parameters. How do I make sure that query params don't get duplicated?

Comment: Where does `DefaultCursorPagination` come from?

Comment: @IainShelvington updated my question